# Calling element from array and setting format of decimals

Tags: objective-c

I have the variable 'elapsedTime':

```
 CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - self.startTime;
```

Which I'm adding multiple times to my array 'test':

```
test addObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:elapsedTime]];
```

Then I'm pulling out values from here, as in:

```
 self.topscore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",test[0]];
```

But I want to pull out the number value with a certain number of decimals. I can usually do this with floats as simply %0.2f, but here it seems my values are stored differently

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `floatValue` method of `NSNumber`:

`self.topscore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[test[0] floatValue]];`

Comment: It's much better to use an `NSNumberFormatter` instead of `stringWithFormat:` so the number is formatted properly based on the user's locale.

Comment: yes, that's true, but in this case it was only asked how the %f can be used again, so this should do the trick. but you are right, `NSNumberFormatter` is of course a more powerful solution.